# How to extract common devDependencies from each package to root package.json file?

Tags: monorepo, lerna

I had imported two existing projects to monorepo using `lerna import <PATH_OF_PROJECT>` command.

Each project has a `package.json` file, they have some common `devDependencies`:

`packages/redux-saga-examples/package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
  "@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.2",
  "jest": "^27.0.6",
  "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
  "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
  "typescript": "^4.3.5"
}
```

`packages/redux-toolkit-example/package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@redux-saga/testing-utils": "^1.1.3",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
  "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
  "jest": "^27.0.4",
  "prettier": "^2.3.1",
  "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
  "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1",
  "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
  "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
  "typescript": "^4.3.4"
}
```

`redux-examples/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --hoist",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Now I want to extract the common `devDependencies` such as `typescript`, `jest`, `@types/jest` to the `devDependencies` of the monorepo root `package.json`. I have tried `lerna bootstrap --hoist`, the `devDependencies` are still there in each package.

Is there any command that `lerna` provides to do this? Expect the `package.json` of root:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --hoist",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

And `package.json` file of each package:

`packages/redux-saga-examples/package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
  "@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.2"
}
```

`packages/redux-toolkit-example/package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@redux-saga/testing-utils": "^1.1.3",
  "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
  "prettier": "^2.3.1",
  "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
  "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if this is still an open question but you can use a command given by lerna

```
lerna link connect
```

This command will segregate dev dependencies from all the packages and put it on the root.